# Customize the design of Facebook account kit Activity

Tags: android

I want to add skip button on Account kit activity.I added the dependencies on gradle . How to customize the accountkit activity. I think it can't handle normal way.because its control is not on our hand.

Comment: What have you tried till now? To get quality answers you should add as much explanation as possible and your current code.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this level of customization is available with Account Kit at this point.  They provide the activities as part of the SDK with limited customization.

Looks like you can really only change color or text, buttons, background,  etc...

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/customizing#advanced